# Rails - Associating database/models with Modules that aren't database tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations

I want to create "associations" (or an equivalent concept with similar methods available from having associations). It is with this table of information, that does NOT need to be updated wahtsoever with other tables that DO involve CRUD.

This is my non-updated table of information:

```
    Table name: Personalities

    personality_type  | alternate_name | CF1 | CF2 | CF3 | CF4 | CF5 | CF6 | CF7 | CF8
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ENTj              | ENTJ           | Te  | Ni  | Se  | Fi  | etc | etc |     |
    INTp              | INTJ           | (more data values)
    ISFj              | ISFP           | (more data values)
    ESFp              | ESFP           | (more data values)
```

So it seems to me that making this non-updated into a database table and performing queries on it would be a silly and pointless way of designing my code, since that would entail all of the query loading time overhead.

So I was thinking of something like making a separate Ruby module, but wasn't sure how to "associate" it with other tables that would be full-fledged database tables with models.

1) How do I associate a non-database class instance based on ActiveRecords::Base with one?

2) Which format/data type should I put my non-updated table of information in?  class, module, multiple class instances, a 2 dimensional array, or 2 dimensional hash?

- My goal in sorting out this decision is to be able to use the similar method notations that comes with associating database models. (e.g. two tables called "Personality" and "User" would allow Rails/Ruby code like `@user.alternate_name.` and `@personality.user.email`).

3) Does the fact that rails uses hidden :id, and timestamp columns affect this in any way?
(If this question is a bit broad, feel free to ignore answering it).
Much thanks!

-A user can have only one personality type.
-Other database models need to refer to personality type information independent of the user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably only the `User` model can have a personality type. Why not create an array of these types as a constant in the `User` model, which you can then refer to in forms etc for selection using `User::PERSONALITY_TYPES`.

For example:

```
class User

  PERSONALITY_TYPES = %w{ ENTJ INTJ ISFP ESFP }

  # ... other model code
end
```

Then simply store the index of the personality type within the array as the user's personality_type_index.

Perhaps I'm oversimplifying your needs, but this is the approach I would start with.

Comment: Ah, should have mentioned other information, but I didn't realize it would come to be important; I wanted to simplify my question as much as possible.

I have other associations as well.
Users can set their own personality type, but there are also characters. Users will cast a "vote" on what they think that character's personality is, through a joining model, say "Declarations". The point being that I will essentially create a poll by having a total vote count of personalities for each character.

Comment: Because of this, my thinking was that I should have some sort of separate entity that contained these personality types, rather than having the concept of personalities wholly within the User model, since other models will need to refer to personality types independent of the User model.

And of course, I would want to keep things DRY by not having to define those methods again in another model.

Comment: Well, you can still avoid adding a `Personality` model by adding counters for each personality type to the `Character` model and allowing users to increment them. However you're starting to describe a configuration complex enough that might warrant its own model ...

Comment: Hypothetically, how would one interface a model with a module?
Is it simply a mixin?
models are classes, so that should be it... right?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A module is just a collection of code you can include. Nothing more.

Comment: So you recommend making a model that is not a database table?

Do you know of any good resources/instructions for doing that?
I've found railscasts #193 and 219 so far.

Comment: With the many-to-many relationship you've described I'd probably start thinking about building a full model, with a table and everything.

Comment: I see, thank you. How can I help you with points? You've certainly helped me, but I think it would be misleading to future readers if I picked this as the chosen answer. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can just give it an up rating rather than selecting it as an answer if you like. I don't mind not getting any points though, I'm just glad it was helpful.